# How to display Tasks in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, google-tasks

Can anyone tell me how to display tasks in my Google Calendar? I can only see my tasks when I go to Gmail. I need the ability to see the tasks in my calendar. When I go to Settings - the Tasks option is not enabled and it will not allow me to click on it.

Comment: I have `Tasks` at the bottom of my list of calendars on the left side, when I click on it it toggles the display of tasks on the right side.  Settings has display tasks enabled and I can't disable it.  I am using Google Apps for Business...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display Tasks in Calender you have to enable it from the left panel under "My Calenders".

Once you click on it, a panel on right with Tasks will appear.

[image]

PS: If you want to Share Tasks you can use my tool http://gmailsharedtasks.com/

Answer (score 1):

Google replaced the Tasks calendar with Reminders. You can switch back by clicking the reminders drop down arrow and select "Switch to Tasks".

[image: image description]

Comment: is this a new feature? What is the benefit of this replacement?